# How to change the font for acronym descriptions using glossaries

Tags: fonts, glossaries

I am using `glossaries` and want to change the appearance of my acronym descriptions to a font *without* serifs.
I managed to change the acronym name but can't seem to find a switch to change the description as well.

Is there an easy way without having to introduce a custom glossary format?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage[
%nomain,
nonumberlist, 
acronym,      
section
]      
{glossaries}

\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textsf{#1}} %Change acronym name font   
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{NVP}{NVP}       {Natural Ventilation Potential}

\begin{document}
\glsaddall
\printglossaries
\sffamily for comparison, this should be without serifs.    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you redefine `\acronymfont` rather?

Answer (score 4):

`\glsnamefont` only affects how the entry name appears in the glossary. For the default `long-short` acronym style, only the short form appears in the `name` field. The long form is put in the `description` field.

> Is there an easy way without having to introduce a custom glossary
>   format?

Not for the base `glossaries` package unless you simply put the entire glossary in sans-serif:

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage[
%nomain,
nonumberlist, 
acronym,      
section
]      
{glossaries}

\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textsf{#1}} %Change acronym name font   

\renewcommand{\glossarypreamble}{\begin{sffamily}}
\renewcommand{\glossarypostamble}{\end{sffamily}}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{NVP}{NVP}       {Natural Ventilation Potential}

\begin{document}
\glsaddall
\printglossaries
\sffamily for comparison, this should be without serifs.    
\end{document}
```

Since you've suppressed the number list, this isn't really any different from setting the `name` and `description` in sans-serif.

[image: image of document]

The alternative (if you don't want to define a new glossary style) is to use the [`glossaries-extra`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) extension package. There are two possible options:

Use the `long-em-short-em` style and change the font command from `\emph` to `\textsf`. This modifies the style both in the document text (if you use `\gls`) and in the glossary:

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage[
%nomain,
nonumberlist, 
acronym,      
section
]      
{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-em-short-em}

\renewcommand*{\glslongemfont}[1]{\textsf{#1}}%
\renewcommand*{\glsabbrvemfont}[1]{\textsf{#1}}%


\newacronym{NVP}{NVP}       {Natural Ventilation Potential}

\begin{document}
\glsaddall
\printglossaries
\sffamily for comparison, this should be without serifs.    
\end{document}
```

[image: image of document]

Alternatively, if you only want to modify the `description` field in the glossary (but not alter the way the long form appears in the document) you can set the `glossdescfont` attribute like this:

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage[
%nomain,
nonumberlist, 
acronym,      
section
]      
{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{glossdescfont}{textsf}
\glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{glossnamefont}{textsf}

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\newacronym{NVP}{NVP}       {Natural Ventilation Potential}

\begin{document}
\glsaddall
\printglossaries
\sffamily for comparison, this should be without serifs.    
\end{document}
```

[image: image of document]

Here I've used

```
\glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{glossnamefont}{textsf}
```

instead of

```
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textsf{#1}}
```

so that the font change only affects acronyms (in case you have a mixture of regular terms and acronyms).

Comment: Is there any equivalent to `\glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{glossnamefont}{emph}` for `symbols` in `glossaries-extra`?

Comment: @bonanza The first argument of `\glssetcategoryattribute` is the category label, so if your symbols are defined with `category=symbol`, then just set the first argument to `symbol`. (A font changing command that works with your symbol commands will need to be selected. For example, if the commands used to display the symbols require math-mode, you might need a maths font command.) See [Setting Styles According to Category](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/sample-name-font.shtml) for more examples.